# Getting error running 'Mongod' to start mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run mongodb, but typing 'mongod' is giving me the error below, do you know how to fix it?

```js
 mongod                        
2021-05-14T15:12:30.819-0400 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=60494 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Chris.local
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-05-14T15:12:30.846-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2021-05-14T15:12:30.848-0400 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2021-05-14T15:12:30.849-0400 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2021-05-14T15:12:30.849-0400 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2021-05-14T15:12:30.849-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2021-05-14T15:12:30.849-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Log file usually contains the clue to debug

You can see in the log

```
2021-05-14T15:12:30.848-0400 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

The directory `/data/db` is not found, you need to create this directory and make sure `mongod` has write permission to this folder.